# Filter an array in object by another array Vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, object

I have feed with json which has one array with object and object with objects: I am try to filter an object which is in array by another array like:

```
persons = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Karl"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Irma"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "David"
    }
]

roles = {
    0: {
        id:  1,
        title: "admin",    
        persons: [1,2],
        status: 
    },
    1: {
        id:  2,
        title: "editor",    
        persons: [1]
    },
    2: {
        id:  3,
        title: "moderator",    
        persons: [3]
    }
}
```

**I try to get roles by person like this, but it doesn't work**

```
roles() {
    return this.roles.filter((el) => { 
        return this.persons.map((id) => { return id }).includes(el) 
    })
},
```

get in Vue

```
<div v-for="(person) in persons">
    <div>
        {{person.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-for="(role) in roles">
        {{role.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**I would like to get a result:**

```
Result: 

    Karl
       - admin
       - editor
    Irma
       - admin
    David
       - moderator
```

Comment: ERROR: `status:` without value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `.filter` on `objects` so you have to get the value using `Object.values` from `this.roles`.

You are filtering the roles which is incorrect instead, you have to map on the `roles` and filter the `persons` if that particulat `person.id` is present in `role.persons`

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-haslett-rcjct?file=/src/App.vue)

```
getRoles() {
  return Object.values(this.roles).map(({ id, title, persons }) => {
    return {
      id,
      title,
      persons: [...this.persons].filter((p) => persons.includes(p.id)),
    };
  });
},
```

Comment: Thank you!   I made mistake in my example.  I fixed it (person by role, but not role by person) Could I use your code in this case?   I am trying to change it for filter like person by role

Answer (score 0):

As always, there will be multiple ways to solve.

Consider using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the value of each `role` before checking if that `role`'s `persons` array contains the `personId` you are searching for.

```js
const persons = [{id:1,name:"Karl"},{id:2,name:"Irma"},{id:3,name:"David"}]
const roles = {0:{id:1,title:"admin",persons:[1,2],},1:{id:2,title:"editor",persons:[1]},2:{id:3,title:"moderator",persons:[3]}}

const getRolesByPersonId = (
  personId
) => {
  return Object.values(roles).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue.persons?.includes(personId)) {
      return [...accumulator, currentValue]
    }
    return accumulator
  }, [])
}

console.log(getRolesByPersonId(1)) // admin, editor
```

I'm not so familiar with Vue, but it might be implemented something like this

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="person in persons" :key="person.id">
        <h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="role in getRolesByPersonId(person.id)" :key="role.id">
            {{ role.title }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      persons: [
        { id: 1, name: "Karl" },
        { id: 2, name: "Irma" },
        { id: 3, name: "David" },
      ],
      roles: {
        0: { id: 1, title: "admin", persons: [1, 2] },
        1: { id: 2, title: "editor", persons: [1] },
        2: { id: 3, title: "moderator", persons: [3] },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getRolesByPersonId(personId) {
      return Object.values(this.roles).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (currentValue.persons?.includes(personId)) {
          return [...accumulator, currentValue];
        }
        return accumulator;
      }, []);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: Edit sad-snow-1w8yw]